# Can't get activity compat to work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I got the following depdencies in the build.gradle (app) file:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   ...
}

...
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
....
```

I have the following repostitories in my build.gradle (project) file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Code which I try to run in my main activity after onCreate:

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

The exact error that I get when I try the above is the following:
 `Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityCompat.`

I have already read all other StackOverflow answers on this problem, but none brought me a solution.

I tried rebuilding the project, syncing with gradle files and file system and I tried to invalidate the caches but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: In gradle, inside `repositories` i also have `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}`.

Comment: @EasyJoinDev After clearing the caches this solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Maybe, you need to import class in the beginning of your java file:     `import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding maven {url "https://maven.google.com"} to the repostitories and clearing the cache with:
File -> Invalidate caches -> Invalidate and exit

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following did the trick for me:

Go to `File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart -> Invalidate Cache and Restart`